# No internet connection after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have upgraded to Windows 10, but all my internet connection are gone.

The internet is working on another laptop. I have a dial-up connection with a modem of MTNL.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29345/discussion-on-question-by-priyanshu-beniwaln-no-internet-connection-after-upgrad).

Answer (score 0):

Installing Drivers will solve this issue and if you don't have the Drivers, download it from your Motherboard's manufacturer site

Comment: can u please send me the URL. my motherboard is of intel. core i5 4 gen

Comment: Intel core i5 is the CPU name its not the MOBO's name.

Comment: where is the mobo name written